# Why are some of the child values being skipped?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some values in my XML file that are being skipped.. Basically, what I want to do is to list every value in the "abrev" tag in one column, and in another column their respective "forme" attribute value. Elements in both columns must ALL DISTINCTS.

Comment: Which one is skipped? Can you provide a smaller XML to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="formes" match="abrev" use="@forme"/>
<xsl:key name="values" match="abrev" use="concat(@forme, '|', normalize-space(.))"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="//abrev[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('formes',@forme))]">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@forme"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('formes',@forme)[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('values',concat(@forme, '|', normalize-space(.))))]"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>                
        </table>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="abrev">
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

BTW, how difficult is it to minimize the example to:

```
<collection>
        <abrev forme="mais">ms</abrev>
        <abrev forme="Mais">ms</abrev>
</collection>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working just fine! I didn't know what exactly was the problem, so I couldn't think of a small example

Answer (score 0):

You created two `<xsl:key>` elements. The second one uses as a key the *value* of the element.

In the following block, during the iteration of the element with `forme="Mais"` you select from `values` the element corresponding to the `"ms"` value, and check if it corresponds to the current element.

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
    select="key('formes',@forme)[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('values',normalize-space(.)))]"/>
```

It doesn't because the `"ms"` value is associated with this `abrev` element:

```
<abrev forme="mais">ms</abrev> sinon<ponc forme=","/>
```

Since the predicate result is false, the template will not be called and the `<td>` will be empty.